# How to add content to a specific cell?

Tags: c#, wpf

Let's say that I've this datagrid definition:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="In corso" Binding="{Binding Path = PlayingMatch}"/>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Terminati" Binding="{Binding Path = TerminatedMatch}" />
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Totali" Binding="{Binding Path = TotalMatch}" />
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

How can I add a value to a specific cell without define a ItemSource? I simply need one rows that contains the value. The final result should be like this:

```
In corso | Terminati | Totali
     4         5         9
```

I've created the property defined in the Path, like this:

```
private int _playingMatch = 0;
public int PlayingMatch
{
     get { return _playingMatch; }
     set { SetField(ref _playingMatch, value); }
}
```

but when I call the property I can see the value setted putting a breakpoint on the set (value), unfortunately there is no new row with the value added. What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

I've added this row to datagrid, I need to simply update dinamically this row with the properties value (PlayingMatch, TerminatedMatch, TotalMatch), how?

```
<DataGrid.Items>
  <RowDefinition />
</DataGrid.Items>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use anonymous object and do this :

```
 Dgrd.Items.Add(new { PlayingMatch="abc",  TerminatedMatch="abc", TotalMatch="12"});
```

And you can clear the `Items` collection using `Dgrd.Items.Clear()` to remove all items from grid.

To change that item,

```
Dgrd.Items.Clear();
Dgrd.Items.Add(new { PlayingMatch = "def", TerminatedMatch = "pqr", TotalMatch = "122" });
```

You can use `dynamic`.

```
dynamic obj = new ObservableCollection<dynamic> { new { PlayingMatch = "abc", TerminatedMatch = "abc", TotalMatch = "12" } };
Dgrd.ItemsSource = obj;
```

Comment: If that does not meet your requirements, tell more what can be done ?

Comment: any other solution such as binding for one row?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your bindings are correct and that Binding is the correct property(Havn't really used the DataGrid). You need to notify the UI that changes has been made to the corresponding property. This is done by implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and calling it as you set the value. There is a lot of guides on the internet for this. Also, you need to specify that the UI should be updated for the property if it changes:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Totali" Binding="{Binding Path = TotalMatch, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Guide for INotifyPropertyChanged:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614(v=vs.100).aspx

Also, if the PropertyChangedEventHandler is null, there is an issue with the binding.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the "DataContext" of your WPF form to point to your controller object that has the getter/setter properties exposed?  If not, it will still run, but not tell you it can't find the "bind" object, but wont crash either.

So, you might need to explicitly add

```
DataContext = myControllerObject;
```

Again, I don't know the form, controller, if you are using MVVM concepts and dont have code in your form directly.

Comment: I already set this, but the problem is misunderstood. I want create a only one row that must be updated dinamically. The problem is that I can't do this via xaml (the properties working well). See my update.